# HTML/CSS Template for Form-Based Apps

Tags: html, css, templates

I do a lot of web apps that mainly rely on forms and I'm wondering of there is some nice HTML/CSS template I could use, at least for my demos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are someones beautiful.

http://www.sixshootermedia.com/free-templates/

Good Luck,

Randolf.

Comment: Also here http://www.oswd.org/